# SpriteKit and UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swift

In my `viewDidLoad` function, I setup a swipe gesture recognizer:

```
var swipeRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("move"))
swipeRecognizer.direction = .Right
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

And then I set up the move function:

```
func move(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    NSLog("swiped")
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I swipe right:

```
[_TtC8swiftris9GameScene move]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc81c200
2014-06-03 14:52:57.560 swiftris[45440:6777826] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[_TtC8swiftris9GameScene move]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc81c200'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined your function as `move(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)`, which maps to the obj-c method name `move:`, but your selector is just `"move"`. You need to use `"move:"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As @Kevin Ballard correctly points out, your selector doesn't match your method, which explains the "unrecognized selector" exception. However, I think it's worth noting that you can ditch the cast to Selector altogether, and use a string literal in its stead.

[Quote from](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf)

> You can construct a selector with a string literal, such as let
>   mySelector: Selector = "tappedButton:". Because string literals can be
>   automatically converted to selectors, you can pass a string literal to
>   any method that accepts a selector.

Example:

```
let gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"move:")
```